# Delete columns from numpy array depending on a condition on a single cell

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Above all, sorry for my bad English.

I have this array `t`:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
       [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
```

I would like to delete the columns where the value of second line is null. Here, I would like to delete the columns 0, 2, 4, 6 and 9, to obtain this array:

```
array([[  1,   0,   5,   7,  8 ],
       [ 11,  13,  15,  17, 18 ]])
```

I tried with `np.sum()` but didn't succeed.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Similar to Juh_, but more expressive, and avoiding some minor unnecessary performance overhead. A grand total of 12 highly pythonic, explicit and unambigious characters. This is really numpy 101; if you are still trying to wrap your head around this, you would do yourself a favor by reading a numpy primer.

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([[ 0,  1,  2,  0,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
              [ 0, 11,  0, 13,  0, 15,  0, 17, 18,  0]])
print a[:,a[1]!=0]
```

Answer (score 6):

With [`numpy.delete`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
a = np.array([[0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 18, 0]])

indices = [i for (i,v) in enumerate(a[1]) if v==0]
# [0, 2, 4, 6, 9]

a = np.delete(a, indices, 1)
# array([[ 1,  0,  5,  7,  8], [11, 13, 15, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: This is a highly non-numpythonic solution. It nullifies one of the main points of numpy, to move loops from python to the C level

Comment: That is if you care about performance. The main reason why I use numpy, is for convenience. But I agree that there are better solutions.

Comment: Upvoting to balance Eelco's unnecessary downvote. This is useful even though it is not the best.

Comment: Upvoting because this is the only answer which actually does what the OP wanted - to remove data from their array.
Yes its nice to play with the strides/indexes to obtain views with just the data you want - but sometimes you just need to delete a row.

Answer (score 2):

Simple (fully numpy) solution:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.array([[ 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [ 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 18, 0]])
indices_to_keep = t[1].nonzero()[0]

print t[:,indices_to_keep]
# [[ 1  0  5  7  8]
#  [11 13 15 17 18]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [`np.where`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
>>> t.T[np.where(t[1])].T
array([[ 1,  0,  5,  7,  8],
       [11, 13, 15, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: Boolean indexing, as in Eelco's answer, is typically faster than `where` + fancy indexing.

Answer (score 0):

I got this working like this:

```
data = array([[ 0, 1, 2, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], [ 0, 11, 0, 13, 0, 15, 0, 17, 18, 0]])
res = array([(a, b,) for a, b in zip(data[0], data[1]) if b]).transpose()
```

got the result

```
In [23]: res
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1,  0,  5,  7,  8],
       [11, 13, 15, 17, 18]])
```

Comment: See eskaev. This is not numpythonic, and loses orders of magnitude of performance relative to the simple numpy solution that exists for this.

Comment: Upvoting to balance Eelco's unnecessary downvote. This is useful even though it is not the best.