# Remove transparent pixels from an image numpy array

Tags: python, opencv, numpy

I have an image's numpy array of shape (224,224,4). Each pixel has 4 dimension - r,g,b,alpha. I need to extract the (r,g,b) values for each pixel where it's alpha channel is 255.

I thought to first delete all elements in the array where alpha value is <255, and then extract only the first 3 values(r,g,b) of these remaining elements, but doing it in simple loops in Python is very slow. Is there a fast way to do it using numpy operations?

Something similar to this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/21017621/4747268

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work: `arr[arr[:,:,3]==255][:,:,:3]`

Comment: [:,:,:3] is giving an error. I changed it to [:,0:3] to fix it.

Comment: @n00b Or simply : `arr[arr[:,:,3]==255,:3]`.

Comment: How would this work if you wanted to change the pixels found here individually to a different RGBA value?

Comment: @MennoVanDijk `arr[arr[:,:,3]==255] = [R,G,B,A]` ?

Answer (score 2):

something like this?

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random((255,255,4))
y = np.where(x[:,:,3] >0.5)
res = x[y][:,0:3]
```

where you have to fit `> 0.5` to your needs (e.g. `==255`). The result will be a matrix with all pixels stacked vertically