# Delete rows that have "nan" in a 66180L X 69L numpy.ndarray

Tags: python, numpy

I have a 600L X 50L numpy.ndarray. Based on the 8th columns, if it has "nan" as a value, I would like to delete that whole row from the numpy.ndarray.

So for example, if the 8th columns had 10 "nan" as its value, I would delete the entire row of where those "nan" are located.

How can I do this?

I know how to do this with a filter button but excel, but want to learn how to do it in python, using numpy.

Thanks :)

Comment: So do you want to filter only on eight specific columns or on the eighth column?

Comment: I want to filter the array based on the eighth column @NicoAlbers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Delete rows from numpy array depending on a condition on a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016684/delete-rows-from-numpy-array-depending-on-a-condition-on-a-single-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016684/delete-rows-from-numpy-array-depending-on-a-condition-on-a-single-cell), but I'll show you how to do that:

For example you have the following array:

```
In [3]: arr = np.eye(4)
In [4]: arr[1,0]=1

In [5]: arr
Out[5]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Then filter with

```
In [30]: arr[arr[:,0]!=0,:]
Out[30]:
array([[1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0.]])
```

of course you can do the same with `nan` values.

Comment: Thank you so much! @NicoAlbers

Comment: You're welcome! But that wasn't that hard to find as a already accepted answer, please consider searching a second time the next time you have such a problem ;-) most of the cases there is already a solution outside :-)

Comment: will do , will better write search questions for future !! :) @NicoAlbers