# How to get rows from a multidimensional numpy array from a single column from the last dimension?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, masking

I have a multidimensional `numpy` array  `a` with dimension `(16, 13, 13, 3, 6)` and I want to only have the rows with the values in `a[...,4:5] >0` , how can I only get the rows which are having `a[...,4:5] > 0` from the last dimension?

```
>>> a.shape
>>>(16, 13, 13, 3, 6)
```

I have tried:

```
a[..., a[...,4:5]> 0]

But, it gives the following error:
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 4; dimension is 6 but the corresponding boolean dimension is 1
```

Which is understandable, so what can I do?
I have also tried the following answers:
[Delete rows from numpy array depending on a condition on a single cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21016684/delete-rows-from-numpy-array-depending-on-a-condition-on-a-single-cell)

But, they don't apply to my case.

Also, what is the difference between `a[...,4:5]` and `a[...,4]` in numpy, I thought they would be the same, but `a[...,4:5].shape` return `(16, 13, 13, 3, 1)` shape and `a[...,4].shape` returns `(16, 13, 13, 3, 3)` shape.

Comment: You discovered the difference.  Reading the `numpy` indexing documentation should make it clear.  Indexing with a scalar reduces the number of dimensions.  Indexing with a slice does not, even if the size of the slice is 1.  That difference applies to plain Python lists as well.

Comment: @hpaulj : Can you explain better, what you're saying and also give an answer to the first part.

Comment: `a[np.squeeze(a[..., 4:5] > 0),...]`?